When calculating expectation values for a smeared field, should everything else also be smeared?
From what I understand, when treating an operator-valued field $\phi(x')$ in QFT, we often smear it over some portion of space with a test function $f_{x}(x')$ which is usually taken to be usually gaussian. As such, we consider states of the form:
$$\int dx'f_{x}(x')\psi(x')|0\rangle=|\Phi(x)\rangle$$
Now, say that I wish to calculate the stress energy tensor for a given Lagrangian, and  calculate its expectation value for our smeared state $|\Phi(x)\rangle$:
$$\langle\Phi(x)|T^{\mu\nu}(x)|\Phi(x)\rangle$$
Now, when calculating $T^{\mu\nu}$, I have two options, one is to calculate it with the smeared fields, such that $T^{\mu\nu}$ is also smeared in some sense, which would allow us to regulate the vacuum fluctuations, or conversely we could calculate $T^{\mu\nu}$ with the the un-smeared fields.
Which is more appropriate to use? Should the field operators in $T^{\mu\nu}$ also be smeared if my state is smeared?

When we do this smearing, we inadvertently introduce a scale given by the size of the test function (width of the Gaussian). This scale does not generally have a physical meaning. So what we end up with does not in general give the correct representation of the physical situation.

The two procedures have a completely different nature.
$$\int d^4x f(x) \Phi(x)|0\rangle \tag{1}$$
defines a generic one-particle state. Varying $f$ in $C_0^\infty(M)$ you have a dense subspace of the one-particle space of the Fock space.
$$\Phi(x)\:, \quad \Phi(x) |0\rangle$$
alone are just  formal objects. The former is an operator valued distribution.  In other words only $\Phi(f):= \int d^4x f(x) \Phi(x)$ is a well defined operator and it can act on any state vector like $|0\rangle$ in its (dense) domain.
$$\int d^4x g(x) :T_{\mu\nu}:(x)$$
is the smeared normally ordered stress energy tensor and embodies two operations:
(a) normal ordering (in Minkowski theory it is equivalent to subtarct the contribution of the vacuum),
(b) smearing procedure with a smooth compactly supported function $g$.
$T_{\mu\nu}(x)$
alone  does not exist properly. To be defined as an operator-valued distribution $:T_{\mu\nu}:(x)$ it needs to be normally-ordered. This distribution smeared with a function $g$ produces a (densely defined) operator, indicated by $\int d^4x g(x) :T_{\mu\nu}:(x)$, which can act on state vectors. Not only the ones defined in (1), but also containing many particles as $\Phi(f_1)\cdots \Phi(f_N)|0\rangle$ and even more complicated states.
In summary, to deal with true expectation values, you should use both smearing procedures (and the normal ordering procedure):
$$\langle 0|\Phi^\dagger(f) \int d^4x :T_{\mu\nu}:(x) g(x) \Phi(f)|0\rangle\:.$$

For a free scalar field with Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi - m^2\phi^2)$, the classical stress-energy tensor is:
$$T^{\mu\nu}(x) = \partial^\mu\phi(x)\partial^\nu\phi(x) - \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\alpha\phi(x)\partial^\alpha\phi(x) - m^2\phi^2(x))$$
In quantum theory, this expression involves products of field operators at the same point, leading to operator product singularities. To handle these, we implement point-splitting by separating the field operators by a small spacetime vector $\epsilon$. Additionally, we need to symmetrize the expression to ensure the operator is Hermitian:
$$T^{\mu\nu}(x,\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\partial^\mu\phi(x+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\partial^\nu\phi(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}) + \partial^\nu\phi(x+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\partial^\mu\phi(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2})\right] - \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}[\partial_\alpha\phi(x+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\partial^\alpha\phi(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}) - m^2\phi(x+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\phi(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2})]$$
Even with point-splitting, taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ leads to divergences. These can be analyzed through the two-point function:
$$\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle = \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{e^{-ik\cdot(x-y)}}{k^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon}$$
The short-distance expansion of this two-point function for small $\epsilon$ contains divergent terms like $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ and $\ln(\epsilon^2)$, as well as finite terms. The renormalized stress-energy tensor is obtained by subtracting these divergences and taking the limit:
$$T^{\mu\nu}_{ren}(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} [T^{\mu\nu}(x,\epsilon) - T^{\mu\nu}_{div}(x,\epsilon)]$$
where $T^{\mu\nu}_{div}(x,\epsilon)$ contains the identified divergent terms.
In curved spacetime, additional geometric terms appear in $T^{\mu\nu}_{div}(x,\epsilon)$ involving the Ricci tensor, Ricci scalar, and their derivatives. The renormalization procedure must absorb these divergences into redefined gravitational coupling constants.
In conformal field theory, the stress-energy tensor can be analyzed using operator product expansions. In 4D, the OPE of two stress tensors has the form:
$$T^{\mu\nu}(x)T^{\rho\sigma}(y) \sim \frac{c}{|x-y|^8}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma} + ...$$
where $c$ is the central charge characterizing the number of degrees of freedom in the theory. The specific power of $|x-y|$ and the structure of subleading terms depend on the spacetime dimension.
The renormalized stress-energy tensor satisfies the conservation law $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{ren} = 0$, ensuring energy-momentum conservation. In some cases, particularly in theories with gauge symmetries or in curved spacetime, additional finite renormalizations may be necessary to preserve symmetries, potentially leading to anomalies.

Thank you for your response, I've seen a similar procedure before and found it very interesting. The reason I raised my question was due to the paper "Vacuum energy density fluctuations in Minkowski and Casimir states via smeared quantum fields and point separation" by Hu and Phillips in which they use a similar method to what you describe, whilst also using smeared fields in $T^{\mu\nu}$, however they take the vacuum expectation value. With this procedure you don't need to subtract the divergent terms, but you still need to smear the stress energy tensor.
